# Node/express Async function res.send appearing in console and not in page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

I have some code that gets some data from a mongo database.

The function inside the express app.get will show in the browser url but in this code the results is appearing only in the console and not in the web page, as it should.

Here is the code:

```
async function showdb() {

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db('mydb');
      dbo.collection('test').findOne({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
        // res.send(result); // commented out
        // db.close(); // commented out
      });
    });

  }
```

Now the route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    showdb().then(result => {
        res.send(result); // result is showing in the console
    })

})
```

`res.send(result);` should show the data in the browser but it's showing it in the console.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's in the console displaying? And what is its type?

Comment: Its displaying this: { _id: 5c9669ee4f401121adb78209, desc: 'This is data'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [MongoClient.connect()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) and [collection.findOne()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findOne)
functions return a Promise, so you can chain them without using callbacks with less code:

```
function showdb() {

  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

  return MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then((db) => {
       return db.db('mydb').collection('test').findOne({});
    });
}
```

Now the `showdb` function will return a Promise to your route.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't included the Port  on which server is listening. Try to add below code this might help you

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', 3000);
var server= app.listen(app.get('port'), function()

{

    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(" Iam at Port:" + " " + port);


});
```

Comment: That's not the case ... that code is at the bottom of the page. If I put th showdb code inside the app.get it works fine. It looks like something to do with the async?